# Char check using while loop in java (BufferedReader)

Tags: java, do-while

```
do
    {

       // asking user choices
       choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        switch(choice)
        {

           // doing something
        }

        System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
        System.out.println("(Y/N)");
        ans = (char) br.read(); 
    }
    while(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');
```

I am using eclipse; 
I want to check whether the user want to re-enter the switch case by entering his answer by a char 'y' || 'Y'. 
But whenever i enter the char 'Y' it enters the do loop but also executes the choice variable. And as the choice variable is int; it throws number format exception.

```
Do you want to continue?
(Y/N)
y
// prints all  my switch options
Exception in thread "main":
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at ArithemeticOperations.main(ArithemeticOperations.java:45)
```

Comment: because once you press enter you also print carriage return and line break as well which are 2 more characters. you will need to check if the entered char is one of them to only execute the switch if its an int

Comment: could you paste your whole code?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Technically this isn't about `Scanner`, but I guess the issue is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that "input string" part of the message? It tells you that the input to the `parseInt` function is empty. And it's empty because it's the newline after you entered your `y`. You need to read a whole line for the "continue" answer, and get the character from that full line.

Comment: Thanks for providing the logical aspect of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

@SomeProgrammerDude already explained the reason behind your problem. So, i am not repeating it. You can modify your code as given below.

```
String ans;
do{
    // asking user choices
    choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    switch(choice){
       // doing something
    }
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
    System.out.println("(Y/N)");
    ans = br.readline(); 
}while(ans.toLowerCase().equals("y"));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. Though i would  mark @SomeProgrammerDude as the answer for this question; cause it explains the technical aspect of my problem. Nonetheless thanks again for providing the solution to my work.